# Do Piles of Gold like the ones in Gyldenhul Barrow respawn when the dungeon resets?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I couldn't find any information on the piles of gold on either of the wikis except for the ID and the amount of gold it typically yields.

Comment: The UESP wiki notes that the dungeon does not respawn (not all of them do). I can confirm that a long time later in a game it never respawned for me.

Comment: ohhhh so the whole dungeon doesn't reset. well, good thing I decided to leave the piles of gold there and fight my urge to get rich just in case.

Comment: Getting rich is a good thing though. Buy yourself something nice!